# What cells would have the CD3 marker on them (other than T-cells)

Tags: immunology

Do you know of any peripheral blood mononuclear cells that would express any amount (beit low or high) of CD3 on their surface (other than T-cells)?

Answer (score 4):

> CD3 is initially expressed in the cytoplasm of pro-thymocytes, the
>   stem cells from which T-cells arise in the thymus. The pro-thymocytes
>   differentiate into common thymocytes, and then into medullary
>   thymocytes, and it is at this latter stage that CD3 antigen begins to
>   migrate to the cell membrane. **The antigen is found bound to the
>   membranes of all mature T cells, and in virtually no other cell type,
>   although it does appear to be present in small amounts in *Purkinje
>   cells*.** This high specificity, combined with the presence of CD3 at
>   all stages of T cell development, makes it a useful
>   immunohistochemical marker for T cells in tissue sections. The antigen
>   remains present in almost all T-cell lymphomas and leukaemias, and can
>   therefore be used to distinguish them from superficially similar
>   B-cell and myeloid neoplasms.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD3_(immunology)

Comment: Purkinje cells are neurons rather than peripheral blood cells

Answer (score 0):

As you know [CD3 is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD3_%28immunology%29)

> a protein complex and is composed of four distinct chains. In mammals, the complex contains a CD3γ chain, a CD3δ chain, and two CD3ε chains.

[Natural Killer (NK) cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_killer_cell) have been [shown](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1387664) to express CD3 epsilon proteins, but not CD3 delta or gamma.

Also on a side note, there are several other non peripheral mononucleated cells besides Purkinje cells that can express CD3, but mostly in pathological circumstances. For instance [Warthin-Finkeldey cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warthin%E2%80%93Finkeldey_cell), also known as polykaryocyes, [display](http://www.pathologyoutlines.com/topic/lymphnodespolykaryocytes.html) CD3, although the origin of these cells is not certain (they [might be](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1312298) multinucleated T-cells).

(PS: If you want more information on CD3, I found [this](http://www.pathologyoutlines.com/topic/cdmarkerscd3.html) site very interesting.)